# submit the form without output in browser-not even in view source

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i have a simple form which i have to submit again and again but i dont want this to appear in browser. i know i can do by type hidden and in display:none but this will only not throw the output in browser.but when u will click on view source full form code will be shown it means all sources are being loaded in browser so i  was using Php echo i removed the echo and tried the form was not gettting submitted.

this is my form

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {setTimeout(\'document.form1.submit()\',100);}
</script>
<form name="form1" id="form1" action="http://xyzddd.com/xyz/x" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="title" value="style_Unbranded Glass, Zara Jeans, Aldo Sneakers - RE-born - Ditia Laloan " size="45" />
<textarea name="form_content"  id="form_message"  rows="" class="fpost"  style="display:none;" >
style_Unbranded Glass, Zara Jeans, Aldo Sneakers - RE-born - Ditia Laloan [img]http://cdn12.lbstatic.nu/files/looks/medium/2013/10/01/3317975__MG_0091.jpg[/img]
</textarea>
<input type="hidden" value="553" name="fid">
<input type="hidden" value="" name="category">
<input  type="submit" value="S" class="button">
</form>
```

the main intention of doing this is i want to save  my internet data as i have limited and slow connection. if i can submit the form without output anything in browser then i can save almost all data and one thing i can not submit the form from cron as it requires users login. so i have to do from browsers only

Comment: 1. do you want to submit form only one time or each 100 miliseconds? 2. why do you need submit button?

Comment: @Dagon this is not spam at all .submitting one database data to other database in diff format. i hate spam. i have also faced lot of spam

Comment: @IlyaBursov  its not 100 miliseconds ater form is submitted i am giving 3 sec gap then coming to this page

Comment: @Dagon i am telling its not spam.if u know help or just say i dont know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can generate and submit the form using jQuery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(
function(){
//generate the form
$('<form/>',{
'name'      : 'form1',
'id'        : 'form1',
'action'    : 'http://xyzddd.com/xyz/x',
'method'    : 'post'
}).appendTo('body');


$('<input>',{
'type'      : "hidden",
'name'      : "title",
'value'     : "style_Unbranded Glass, Zara Jeans, Aldo Sneakers - RE-born - Ditia Laloan ",
'size'      :"45" // not necesary since it`s hidden ....
}).appendTo('#form1');

$('<textarea>'.{
'name'      : "form_content",
'id'        : "form_message"
'class'     : "fpost",
'style'     : "display:none;"
'html'      : 'style_Unbranded Glass, Zara Jeans, Aldo Sneakers - RE-born - Ditia Laloan [img]http://cdn12.lbstatic.nu/files/looks/medium/2013/10/01/3317975__MG_0091.jpg[/img]'
}).appendTo('#form1');


$('<input>',{
'type'      : "hidden",
'name'      : "fid",
'value'     : "553"
}).appendTo('#form1');

$('<input>',{
'type'      : "hidden",
'name'      : "category",
'value'     : ""
}).appendTo('#form1');

setTimeout(
function() {
var serial = $('form1').serialize();
// i hope http://xyzddd.com/xyz/x is actualy a php ...
$.post( "http://xyzddd.com/xyz/x", serial);
}, 100);

})


</script>
```

Comment: sorry for messy code ... this can not be viewd in "view source", but it will load the server, sice you post one every 100ms ...

Comment: its client side, its clearly viewable in source

Comment: @Dragon this is the best way i cna think of .... if you want a form ... else, you can simply use $.post with variables ...  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/  [link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Comment: @user3026718 and i got a vote down ... i just love this guys...

Comment: he is a useless guy.dont know anything

Comment: @Dagon poor dagon ould not stop spammer :)